# tf.cond can not be serialized correctly?

Tags: python, serialization, tensorflow

Can a graph which using `tf.cond` be exported by `SerializeToString`?
I'm doing some preprocess of a CNN model which requires an input size of at least 224, and I want to make sure the input image is resized to 224 when it's smaller than that size, and do nothing if the image is bigger than that.

The following code could work as expected.The `sess.run(...)` result shows that the image is resized correctly.Then I exported(serialized) the whole graph into a `.pb` file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

input_jpeg = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='DecodeJpeg/contents')
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(input_jpeg, channels=3)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
height = tf.constant(224)
width = tf.constant(224)
def resize_t(image_t, h=height, w=width):
  image2 = tf.expand_dims(image_t, axis=0)
  image2= tf.image.resize_bilinear(image2, [h, w], align_corners=False)
  image2 = tf.squeeze(image2, [0])
  return image2
input_h = tf.shape(image)[0]
input_w = tf.shape(image)[1]
# seems logical_or can not work here...why?
#condition = tf.logical_or(tf.less(input_h, height), tf.less(input_w, width))
#image_checked = tf.cond( condition, lambda:resize_t(image), lambda:image)

image_checked = tf.cond(
    (tf.less(input_h, height)),
    lambda:resize_t(image), lambda:image)
image_checked = tf.cond(
    (tf.less(input_h, height)),
    lambda:resize_t(image), lambda:image)
shape_t = tf.shape(image_checked, name='shape_t')

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # a pic which is smaller than 224x224
  with open('1.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
  shape_value = sess.run(shape_t, feed_dict={input_jpeg:content})
  # with an output:
  # [224 224   3]
  # it works fine until now ...
  print(shape_value)

  # write the graph to pbtxt
  tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def,
     './', 'proto.pbtxt', True)

  # freeze the graph and export
  output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess, sess.graph_def, ['shape_t'])
  output_graph_def = graph_util.remove_training_nodes(output_graph_def)
  with open('out.pb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

As the `out.pb` file is successfully generated, I tried to import the file with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with open('out.pb', 'rb') as f:
  graph_content = f.read()
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(graph_content)
_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```

The operation is failed with the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "im.py", line 6, in <module>
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 342, in import_graph_def
    % (input_name,)))
ValueError: graph_def is invalid at node u'cond_1/ExpandDims/dim': More inputs specified ('cond_1/Switch:1') than the op expects..
```

It seems that the op `expand_dims` received an unexpected parameter `cond_1/Switch:1`, and the `.pbtxt` file generated by `tf.train.write_graph` shows that there **is** an additional input added to the `expand_dims/dim`:

```
node {
  name: "cond_1/ExpandDims/dim"
  op: "Const"
  input: "^cond_1/switch_t"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_INT32
        tensor_shape {
        }
        int_val: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which should be (when expand_dim/resize is executed unconditionally):

```
node {
  name: "ExpandDims/dim"
  op: "Const"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_INT32
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "value"
    value {
      tensor {
        dtype: DT_INT32
        tensor_shape {
        }
        int_val: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Did I misunderstand something? How can I use `tf.cond` with an exported `.pb` file?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm having the same problem.